# how to get multiple inputs type date values to console with checking if empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have six inputs type date, four of them are read-only. When I choose a date on the first one, I calculate that date and put the values on the read-only inputs, and I choose a date in the last input after that I click the button.
I want to console.log() all of the dates, and get errors if the the inputs are empty.

As you can see in the picture, only the first and last dates are logged because the OnChange event is triggered, but I want to log the the other two in red too, and it's not working out with me

Here's what I have done:

```
import { React, useState } from "react";
import moment from "moment";


export default function Test() {

  const [date, setdate] = useState({ date1: "", date2: "", date3: "", date4: "" });
  const [error, seterror] = useState("");



  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    setdate({
      ...date,
      [event.target.name]: value
    });
  }

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (date.date1 === "" || date.date4 === "") {
      seterror("error")

    } else {
      console.log("bye")
      seterror("")
      console.log(date)

    }
  };

  function addDays(date, days) {
    if (!date) {
      return ''
    } else {
      var result = new Date(date);
      result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
      var res = moment(result).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
      return res;
    }

  }



  return (
    <div>
      <div className="widget widget-chart-one">

        <form>

          <label>تاريخ القرار</label>
          <input type="date" className="form-control" name="date1" onChange={handleChange}
          />


          <label>تاريخ النشر  </label>

          <div className="form-group row  mb-6">
            <div className="col-sm-6">
              <input type="date" className="form-control" value={date.date1} readOnly />

            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-6">
              <input type="date" className="form-control" name="date2" value={addDays(date.date1, 15)} onChange={handleChange} readOnly />
            </div>
          </div>
          <label >فترة البحث العمومي  </label>

          <div className="form-group row  mb-6">
            <div className="col-sm-6">

              <input type="date" className="form-control" value={addDays(date.date1, 15)} readOnly />
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-6">
              <input type="date" className="form-control" name="date3" value={addDays((addDays(date.date1, 15)), 9)} onChange={handleChange} readOnly />
            </div>
          </div>
          <label>تاريخ الاجتماع</label>
          <div className="form-group row  mb-10">
            <div className="col-sm-12">
              <input type="date" className="form-control" name="date4" onChange={handleChange} />

            </div>

          </div>
          <button className="mr-2 btn btn-primary" type="submit" onClick={handleClick}> تأكيد</button>
          <div>
            {error && <small className="text-danger"> {error} </small>}
          </div>


        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make changes in your state

```
const [date, setdate] = useState({date1:'', date2:'', date3: '', date4:''});
```

Then make following changes in your handleChange Event

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
        const selectedDate =    event.target.value
        setdate({
            date1: selectedDate,
            date2: addDays(selectedDate, 5),
            date3: addDays(selectedDate, 15),
            date4: addDays((addDays(date, 15)), 9),
        })
  }
```

Then make below changes in your inputs

First Input

```
<input type="date" className="form-control" value={date.date1} readOnly />
```

Second Input

```
<input type="date" className="form-control" value={date.date2} readOnly />
```

Third Input

```
<input type="date" className="form-control" value={date.date3} readOnly />
```

Fourth Input

```
<input type="date" className="form-control" value={date.date4} readOnly />
```

Comment: the fourth date is not calculated, its chosen, how can I do that? in here:  setdate({
            date1: selectedDate,
            date2: addDays(selectedDate, 5),
            date3: addDays(selectedDate, 15),
            date4: addDays((addDays(date, 15)), 9),
        })

Comment: are you talking about name="date2"?

Comment: yes, two dates are readonly and the other two are not, the user choose the date

Comment: Add onChange event handler for date2. Then you can check in that function if date1 or date2 or date3 is empty or not. If it's empty then show error.

Comment: Did you tried or not?

Comment: The onchange event is not working on date2, because I don't change it manually, it just displays the calculated date

Comment: I added a picture to explain my problem more, I also updated the code to what I have currently

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand from the picture.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative quick solution would be to perform a check if `date` is defined / non-empty string before adding the days.

```
<input type="date" className="form-control" {date ? `value=${addDays(date, 15)}` : `value=""` readOnly/>
```

Or on the function level

```
function addDays(date, days) {
  if (!date) return '';
  ...
}
```

Otherwise, I'd make a small change in the condition statement in case you simply want to check if they're empty.

```
if (!isNaN(date.date1)||!isNaN(date.date2)) {
```

into

```
if (!date || !date.date1 || !date.date2) {
```

Comment: It's not only a check, it shows an error message

Comment: Check my updated answer to see if that answers your question, it's quite unclear what you want to achieve.